# Angular VS Code error tsc file.ts error no está está firmado digitalmente

Tags: typescript, vscode

Tengo una duda con **Angular 8**, estoy partiendo con el "hola mundo" con Visual Studio Code

app.ts

```
console.log('hola mundo typescript');
```

index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Ejemplo1</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Luego en **Terminal** ejecuto:

```
tsc .\app.ts
```

y me da error

```
tsc : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\hgonzalez\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1. El archivo C:\Users\hgonzalez\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 no 
está firmado digitalmente. No se puede ejecutar este script en el sistema actual. Para obtener más información acerca de la ejecución de scripts y 
la configuración de la directiva de ejecución, consulta about_Execution_Policies en https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ tsc .\app.ts
```

Tengo instalado VS Code

```
npm –v    
6.11.3

tsc -v    
3.63

ng v  (angular Cli)
8.3.7
```

Comment: No estás usando Angular en el código, el problema está en el compilador de Typescript

Comment: Por otro lado, parece un tema de permisos: Windows no permite la ejecución de scripts no firmados digitalmente

Answer (score 5):

En la consola de windows o en visual studio code, como administrador, lista las politicas con: *get-ExecutionPolicy -list*
Despues le asignas al usuario actual la politica: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

[image: Proceso de asiganción al usuario actual la politica de ejecución de scripts firmados remotamente]

Y ya con esto deberia funcionarte bien.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Luego de un rato descubrí que funciona usando **CMD de Windows**. No es necesario entrar como Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Tenes los permisos suficientes para ejecutar scripts en la LocalMachine sin embargo el problema esta en el current user. Las soluciones que te han dado son para habilitar los scripts a nivel "general" por asi decirlo, pero no resolvera tu problema. El comando que nescesitas en tu caso es:

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted -scope CurrentUser
```

Dale a la [O] (si a todo) y despues comprueba con

```
get-executionpolicy -list
```

que tanto en la LocalMachine como en el CurrentUser tenes Unrestricted

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    Unrestricted
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

Y listo ya te funcionara

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciona así:
https://www.alexmedina.net/habilitar-la-ejecucion-de-scripts-para-powershell/

Si abrimos el Windows PowerShell como administrador y ejecutamos el comando «Get-ExecutionPolicy» nos tendría que devolver «Unrestricted» o lo que es lo mismo «Restringido». Para cambiar esta configuración basta con ejecutar «Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted».

Answer (score 0):

Genial listo ya me funciono muchas gracias por el aporte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los agradecimientos se dan _votando a favor_. Podrás hacerlo cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges). Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), podrás [votar a favor de preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/359065)